# No suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "calc<int>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this following code that I would like to apply operator overloading to:

```
template < class T>
class calc
{
public:

    T multiply(T x, T y);
    T add (T x, T y);
};

template < class T>
T calc<T>::multiply(T k1, T k2)
{
    return k1 * k2;
}

template < class T>
T calc<T>::add(T k1, T k2)
{
    return k1 + k2;
}

int main()
{
    calc<int> c;
    std::cout << c.multiply(1, 5);
}
```

I have attempted to implement operator overloading, but I have an error: E0415  no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "calc". Line: calc a(1);

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < class T>
class calc
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;
};

template < class T>
calc<T> operator*(calc<T> const&  k1, calc<T> const&  k2)
{
    calc<T> ret;
    ret.x = k1.x * k2.x;
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    calc<int> a(1);
    calc<int> b(5);
    calc<int> result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to make a constructor.

Comment: So why don't you just provide a suitable constructor like the compiler demands?

Comment: The question has two **different** definitions of the `calc` template. Which one are you asking about? Remove the other one.

Comment: Okay so what did you want `calc<int> a(1)` to do?

Answer (score 1):

When using classes there must be something called a constructor that will initialize the class. That way the variables of that class are set and can be used in the member functions. A constructor doesn't have a return type (not even void) and is always named after the name of the class. So in your case the code would look something like this:

```
calc<T> (int value)
{
    x=value;
}
```

or

```
calc<T> (int value)
{
    y=value;
}
```

In your first example of code, the program calls the default constructor which is made for you automatically by the compiler. It would look something like this:

```
calc<T> ()
{
    //since there is nothing to assign. Do nothing.
}
```

However if you were to call the default constructor in the second example of code, the x and y values would be assigned the default value of T for that
compiler.

Now that you have a constructor the item in that object is saved. So that, a.x 
or a.y will equal the value that was sent into the constructor. (In your case 1).

Comment: Nitpick: constructors don't have names :P

Comment: _"However if you were to call the default constructor in the second example of code, the x and y values would be assigned the default value of T for that compiler."_ More likely they'd have an unspecified value, particularly since you chose T=int

Comment: Don't know what you mean about "multiplying 2 templates together" - unless you're referring to the fact that this operation will fail for T=string, but that's generally considered a feature not a bug

Comment: Yes, according to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c they do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, You are right. A template can be multiplied together, but if you were to multiply when the template was a string, you'd get compiler errors.

Comment: I can accept what that is saying.  However, using the term "declarator" might be confusing to someone who is new to programming. Hence, the term "name."

Comment: It would be better if someone new to programming learned the correct things, not the wrong things.